# Remove Adobe Edge from HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe-edge

I have a html package that is dynamically loading Adobe Edge Animations into a holder div, but when reload the file into the div again the Edge animation does not run as it should and parts appear randomly.

I have made a function to remove all the called in Javascript files that Edge loads in and the div gets cleared of all HTML. Does anyone know if there is anything else I am missing? Or anything else I need to remove?

Comment: I dont think there is anything we can do about this, after trawling the net I think Adobe will need build something into edge or add an API for unloading

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this with an iframe, just loaded the edge anim into an iframe within the div, when this is cleared and rewritten the edge anim comes in and plays fine.